# Why is this Perl script running forever?

Tags: perl, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am attempting to track amazon prices using a perl script. This should capture html from Amazon and search for a pattern and print the previous 30 lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $pattern = "SuperSaverShipping";
my $url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00BF9MZ80";
my $response = "";
do {
  print "Sending HTTP req to www.amazon.com\n";
  my $response = `curl -s $url | grep -n -B 30 '$pattern'`;
  print "Response received as:\n$response\n";
  sleep(2);
} until ($response ne "");
print "\nresponse stored.\n";
```

The reason for the while loop is that sometimes amazon sometimes with a server error. I want the script to loop until it catches html from amazon. The script outputs something like this until I kill it:

```
Sending HTTP req to www.amazon.com
Response received as:

Sending HTTP req to www.amazon.com
Response received as:
1687-    
1688-    
1689-
1690-
1691-
1692-
1693-    <span class="a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold">        $132.29    </span>
1694-    <span class="a-color-price">
1695-        
1696-
1697-    </span>
1698-
1699-
1700-        <br>
1701-        <span class="a-color-secondary">
1702:            & <b>FREE Shipping</b>. <a href="/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=527692&pop-up=1" target="SuperSaverShipping" onclick="
return amz_js_PopWin('/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=527692&pop-up=1','SuperSaverShipping','width=550,height=550,resizable=1,scrollbars
=1,toolbar=0,status=0');">Details</a>
Sending HTTP req to www.amazon.com
Response received as:

Sending HTTP req to www.amazon.com
Response received as:
```

I have also tried changing the until() condition to `until (length($response) > 5)` and I get the same output. Can someone please tell me why this is ending when `$response` is holding the html?

Perhaps it is something to do with the output being stored in an array, but I dont fully understand how that works in Perl. Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the two `$response` variables are different.  Remove the inner `my` and things should start working.